# Call app.use/app.post (which INSERT INTO a db) to get form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I created an app.use with express in order to INSERT values in a database. I want to get those values when user clicks register.

My form:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST">
<h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>
<label for="inputEmail" id="lblEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email 
address" name="email" required autofocus>
<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Password" name="passworf" required>
<label for="repeatInputPassword" class="sr-only">Repeat Password</label>
<input type="password" id="repeatinputPassword" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Repeat Password" required>
<label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
<input type="name" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" 
name="name" required>
<label for="surname" class="sr-only">Surname</label>
<input type="surname" id="inputSurname" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Surname" name="surname" required>
<div class="checkbox mb-3">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btnblock-" 
type="submit">Register</button>
<p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
</form>
```

app.use used in order to insert values in the database. Am using MySQL below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var http = require('http');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.use('/', urlencodedParser, function(req,res, next){
var adminUser = req.body.email;
var adminPass = req.body.password;
var adminName = req.body.name;
var adminSurname = req.body.surname;
console.log(req.body);
var sql = "INSERT INTO admins VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";
con.query(sql, [ adminUser, adminPass, adminName, adminSurname], 
  function(error, rows, fields){
    if(!!error) {
        console.log('Query Failed' + error.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Query Successful');
        console.log(rows.insertId);
        next();
    }
  });
 })

app.listen(5500);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to submit an html form?

Comment: am asking how to call the app.use when I click submit button

Comment: Then, yes, you're asking how to submit an html form.

Comment: For starters, your form is missing an opening tag.

Comment: in my code editor is okay, probably is missing just here. I've tested the form and it is okay

Comment: I fixed it here as well. I added <form class="form-signin" method="POST">

Comment: If your input doesn't have a name, it's value won't be sent to the server.

Comment: do you mean I need to input a name in <form> opening tag ?

Comment: No, i mean your inputs need names.

Comment: aham. okay done that. After that how can app.use be triggered when user clicks register button ?

Comment: That should already be occurring assuming the form is submitting to a matching route.

Comment: @KevinB On the browser console I see {Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at register.js:1} which is {var express = require('express');} Is that related to routing ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [Express POST route](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.post.method) that the form can post too.

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  // Process form here
  var adminUser = req.body.email;
  var adminPass = req.body.password;
  var adminName = req.body.name;
  var adminSurname = req.body.surname;
  // etc.
});
```

The path should match the form [action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_action_attribute) attribute

Answer (score -1):

Your form must be sending the `POST` request to the same route that you defined with `app.use(...)`. In this case, your form is `POST`ing to the same route it is on, which means it needs to be on the `/` route to work.

Change your `app.use(...)` to be `app.post(...)` so that it only handles `POST` requests, then serve the form's html from the same route using:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path-to-form);
})
```

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/won9jzj8k7